# How can I delete order, and place the ordered items in the receipt here?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a Point of Sale in console application using C# language, but I want it to have a feature of deleting orders that the customer stated, and to put the ordered items in the receipt. I was wondering if how can I do that. I hope someone can help me. Here's my code:

```
        decimal B1 = 75, B2 = 129, B3 = 129, C1 = 48, C2 = 65, C3 = 85, D1 = 75, D2 = 75, D3 = 75, E1 = 20, E2 = 35, E3 = 15;
        int qty = 1;
        decimal tax = 3;
        decimal total = 0;

        reset:
        // design
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("                                          WELCOME TO CHEAPEPAY FAST FOOD");
        Console.WriteLine("                                             THE CHEAPEST FOOD IN TOWN");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("         ========================================================================================================");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("                          CHICKEN MEAL                                              BURGER                 ");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("                 B1 FRIED CHICKEN WITH RICE                     P 75        C1 PLAIN BURGER         P48");
        Console.WriteLine("                 B2 FRIED CHICKEN WITH SPAGHETTI                P129        C2 CHEESE BURGER        P65");
        Console.WriteLine("                 B3 FRIED CHICKEN WITH FRIES AND BURGER         P129        C3 DOUBLE BURGER        P85");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("                             PASTA                                                   DRINKS");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("                 D1  SPAGHETTI WITH DRINK                       P75          E1 SOFTDRINKS (50OZ)    P20");
        Console.WriteLine("                 D2  PALABOK WITH DRINK                         P75          E2 COKEFLOAT            P35");
        Console.WriteLine("                 D3  PANCIT WITH DRINK                          P75          E3 BOTTLE WATER (50OZ)  P15");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("                                                     ENTER 0 WHEN FINISHED");
        Console.WriteLine("         ========================================================================================================");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.Write("Wanna order? (Y/N): ");

        string order = (Console.ReadLine());
        backorder:

        // choose order
        if (order == "Y" || order == "y")
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Choose Orders:");
            string choose = (Console.ReadLine());

            if (choose == "B1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many items?: ");
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                total = qty * B1 + total;
                Console.WriteLine("Ordered FRIED CHICKEN WITH RICE\nTotal Order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                goto backorder;
            }
            else if (choose == "B2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many items?: ");
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                total = qty * B2 + total;
                Console.WriteLine("Ordered FRIED CHICKEN WITH SPAGHETTI\nTotal Order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                goto backorder;
            }
            else if (choose == "B3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many items?: ");
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                total = qty * B3 + total;
                Console.WriteLine("Ordered FRIED CHICKEN WITH FRIES AND BURGER \nTotal Order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                goto backorder;
            }
            else if (choose == "C1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many items?: ");
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                total = qty * C1 + total;
                Console.WriteLine("Ordered PLAIN BURGER \nTotal Order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                goto backorder;
            }
            else if (choose == "C2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many items?: ");
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                total = qty * C2 + total;
                Console.WriteLine("Ordered CHEESE BURGER\nTotal Order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                goto backorder;
            }
            else if (choose == "C3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many items?: ");
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                total = qty * C3 + total;
                Console.WriteLine("Ordered DOUBLE BURGER\nTotal Order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                goto backorder;
            }
            else if (choose == "D1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many items?: ");
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                total = qty * D1 + total;
                Console.WriteLine("Ordered SPAGHETTI WITH DRINK \nTotal Order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                goto backorder;
            }
            else if (choose == "D2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many items?: ");
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                total = qty * D2 + total;
                Console.WriteLine("Ordered PALABOK WITH DRINK   \nTotal Order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                goto backorder;
            }
            else if (choose == "D3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many items?: ");
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                total = qty * D3 + total;
                Console.WriteLine("Ordered PANCIT WITH DRINK\nTotal Order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                goto backorder;
            }
            else if (choose == "E1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many items?: ");
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                total = qty * E1 + total;
                Console.WriteLine("Ordered SOFTDRINKS (50OZ)\nTotal Order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                goto backorder;
            }
            else if (choose == "E2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many items?: ");
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                total = qty * E2 + total;
                Console.WriteLine("Ordered COKEFLOAT\nTotal Order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
                goto backorder;
            }
            else if (choose == "E3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many items?: ");
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                total = qty * E3 + total;
                Console.WriteLine("Ordered BOTTLE WATER (50OZ)\nTotal Order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                goto backorder;
            }
            // end order, payment
            else if (choose == "0")
            {
                if (total == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No orders!");
                    goto backorder;
                }
                else
                {
                    payment:

                    Console.WriteLine("Total amount of order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
                    Console.WriteLine("============================================================");

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.Write("Cash: ");
                    decimal cash = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (cash < total)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Cash is not enough!\n");
                        goto payment;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Change: P" + (cash - total).ToString("0.00"));
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input!");
                Console.WriteLine();
                goto backorder;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Why not?");
            goto end;

        }

        Console.Write("\n\nDo you want receipt? (Y/N): ");

        //receipt

        string receipt = (Console.ReadLine());
        if (receipt == "Y" || receipt == "y")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("                                          WELCOME TO CHEAPEPAY FAST FOOD");
            Console.WriteLine("                                             THE CHEAPEST FOOD IN TOWN");
            Console.WriteLine("                                         Lakandula St. , Mariveles, Bataan");
            Console.WriteLine("                                                    09077112400");
            
            Console.WriteLine("Subtotal: P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
            Console.WriteLine("Tax: P" + tax.ToString("0.00"));
            Console.WriteLine("Grand Total: P" + (total + tax).ToString("0.00"));
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for buying! Come again!");
            Console.WriteLine("============================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for buying! Come again!");
        }

        //order again
        
        Console.WriteLine("\nDo you want to order again?");
        string ag = (Console.ReadLine());
        if (ag == "Y" || ag == "y")
        {
            goto reset;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("See you soon! Take care!");
        }
        end:
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Comment: _"goto backorder;"_ - just: **NO**! GOTO => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/branches-and-loops?tutorial-step=3 .. and then forget that `goto` and labels are even supported.

Comment: _"but I want it to have a feature of deleting orders that the customer stated, and to put the ordered items in the receipt"_ - what do you mean by that? Like it having a remark like `"SomeItem - [Cancelled]"` ?

Comment: The `if else if else if else if ...` can be replaced by a `switch case`. The contents are very similar. I suggest you to create functions instead of repeating again and again your code. Replace your `goto`s by proper code flow, you're writting [Spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)

Comment: And something else not so techy: "Cheap" is often read as "low quality". So you may want to reconsider the wording.

Answer (score 0):

You may add additional menu items to delete/remove from receipt.  For example:

```
Console.WriteLine("                DB1 DELETE FRIED CHICKEN WITH RICE");
```

Then add delete code into the choice if else structure:

```
else if (choose == "DB1")
{
    Console.WriteLine("How many items to delete?: ");
    qty = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    total -= qty * B1;
    Console.WriteLine("** DELETED ** FRIED CHICKEN WITH RICE\nTotal Order is P" + total.ToString("0.00"));
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
    goto backorder;
}
```

Comment: I think OP needs to take a step back, do a "feature freeze" and fix the code that's already there. From what's in the question, OP will soon hit a wall.